# how to analyze jscode in dart project

Tags: dart, dart-pub

could someone help me? I'm trying to use the Puppeteer library (https://pub.dev/packages/puppeteer) in my Dart project. Everything is going well, but the problem is that Puppeteer is a Node.js library, not native to Dart. In my Dart project, I need to use JavaScript code as a string. However, my IDE (VS Code) cannot analyze this code because it is treated as a string, resulting in frequent syntax errors. Is there any way to analyze JavaScript code within a Dart project while writing the code? Here's an example:

[red color is js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voURH.png)

i try to search information in google.